# Tools/Eclipse Plugins to generate DAO's Pojo's and JSP's from MySql tables?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsp, dao

Does anyone know if there are any eclipse plug-ins that can generate jsp's(using EL) from pojo's after using JPA in eclipse EE?

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: You need to narrow down this question, as it is, it will likely be closed as 'Not Constructive'. Try and focus on one question at a time, and definitely show that you have done some research on your own, then run into a roadblock for which you need help.

Comment: In the meantime, download and install the EE version of Eclipse. If you right click a project and select New, you have the option (under Other->JPA) to create entities from tables.

Comment: @Perception I don't think the question is to general, see answer

Answer (score 3):

You can try **Telosys** (see http://www.telosys.org) a simple code generator for scaffolding.

This tool is provided as an Eclipse plugin (among others).

If necessary, it's possible to adapt the templates in order to generate pure JSP

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to look into [JBoss Forge](http://forge.jboss.org/) and [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo). 
Both of these are rapid prototype and scaffolding tools similar to [Rails scaffolding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaffold_%28programming%29#Scaffolding_in_Ruby_on_Rails). 
They are executed from command line (don't be afraid it is very simple) but there are plugins for both of them for eclipse.
A quote from Forge :

> A core framework for rapid-application development in a
>   standards-based environment. Plugins / incremental project enhancement
>   for Java EE, and more.

Generally it is simpler to go with Forge if you are more on Java EE 6 stack and to go with Spring Roo if you are using Spring. Currently Forge is lot cleaner conceptually since it does not use AspectJ or any other similar black magic.

Comment: Wow, these are pretty extensive tools. I suppose if I was going to do development work professionally I'd definitely consider investing the time to learn JBoss, Forge, or Roo. I've got my hands full with eclipse Juno using Tomcat6 and jdk 6. Is it possible there might be a smaller plug-in that will auto-generate DAO's and JSP's from tables? It would seem that JPA is here to stay? So, maybe a tool to generate jsp's from JPA's entities might be what I'm looking for.